# Which is the most trusted bhagvat gita version available?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

There are many versions of bhagavd gita.

I am reading one provided by iskcon. But if at all, there is version with better description and contents.

Which one is the best to refer?

Comment: `Geetapress gorakhpur` is most trusted and widely used publisher for hindu religeous books.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend the ISKCON version. The word to word translations are good but the commentary isn't. It puts too much focus on Bhakti drowning the larger message.  I'd recommend the one by Swami Dayananda Saraswati(Arsha Vidya Gurukulam).